# Verify $(\cot A - \tan A)/(\cot A + \tan A)=\cos2A$

Tags: trigonometry

What are the steps to prove that this equation is and identity?

$$\frac{\cot A - \tan A}{\cot A + \tan A}=\cos2A$$

Comment: It should be $\cot A$ in RHS., To prove this, first convert the LHS in $\sin$ and $\cos$, and do cancellations. You'll see $\cos 2A$ in the numerator and $\sin 2A$ in denominator.

Comment: Rather, $\cot2A,$ no?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that
$$
\cot A-\tan A=\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}-\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}
=\frac{\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A}{\sin A\cos A}
$$
and
$$
\cot A+\tan A=\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}+\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}
=\frac{\cos^2 A+\sin^2 A}{\sin A\cos A}
$$

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the left-hand side of your equation (denominator and numerator) by $$\tan(x)\ne 0$$ we get
$$\frac{1-\tan(x)^2}{1+\tan(x)^2}=\frac{\cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^2}{\cos(x)^2+\sin(x)^2}=\cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^2=\cos(2x)$$
note that $$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$ and $$\cos(x)\ne 0$$